# Uploading simple boilerplate project to AWS with Elastic Beanstaclk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, angular, webpack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to upload this [Angular2 boilerplate](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) to `AWS` using `Elastic Beanstalk`.

What are the necessary steps regarding server side? Do I have to write my own `server.js` file or `npm` start command?

If so, what do I specify as static?

Comment: I think your question is a bit broad, it's better to research/try yourself first and then ask more specific questions on SO when/if you run into trouble. :)

Comment: Formatting and clarification of the question

Comment: I am honestly really confused about the process to upload in that boilerplate. Do I just upload the dist folder? Do I need to have a server.js file with node? I did try to investigate but I get quite stuck

Comment: I believe I can ask a more specific question now. I created a dist folder and lets assume it is a valid dist folder with everything I need. Do I need to write a node server and serve only the dist folder? Should the node server be inside that dist folder?